# How to configure gradle to delete unused fonts from assets directory?

Tags: android, gradle

We have a base UI library that includes couple of fonts as the company-wide design guideline and we only use these fonts.

I've also configured my `build.gradle` to the topmost size-reduction configuration I've come to know and search on the Internet:

```
defaultConfig {
    resConfigs "en"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

But when I analyze the released `apk` via Android Studio, I see that unused fonts are still there and has not been removed.

Of course I can remove them manually and make a build, and then return them to the base library. But that's not efficient and won't be working in scale or in teamwork.

Is there a way to configure gradle to omit/drop/shake/shrink/delete unused fonts in builds?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to know unused assets during compile-time, because assets are generally accessed using `context.getAssets().open(fileName);` where `fileName` can be any `String`.

I suggest you to store fonts in raw directory and access them as resources.

You can take help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10918500/5137352) to load fonts from resources.

Once you load fonts from resources, then you can easily use the option `shrinkResources true` in gradle to remove unused resources.

Modifying the base UI library might not be an option for you, I'm just giving my suggestion as it may help other people.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. As you mentioned that's not a feasible option right now for me. But I'll definitely present it to the team.